# Enterprise Architect Source Import does not recognize public fixed byte myArray[4]

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have a C# source file which contains the field declaration

```
public fixed byte myArray[4];
```

which Enterprise Architect (12.0.1215) complains about ("Unexpected symbol: [") when I do an import of the source file via Code Engineering > Import Source Directory. Is there something I can do about it (except changing the code which is not a viable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of EA are you on, and which version of C# (.Net) are you using?

If you are using an old version of EA maybe then it could be that C# you are trying to import was not supported yet.

If it doesn't work on the latest version of EA you better contact Sparx support. They can probably help you further.

If all else fails you could define your own version of the C# language by creating your own [grammar](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/software_engineering/grammar_editor_for_imported_co.html), but that is far from easy.

I suspect the `fixed` keyword is the culprit in this case.

Comment: As you suggested I turned to the EA support team to discuss the issue. Will update my question as soon as I know more.

Comment: The EA support team responded to me that they were able to reproduce the issue: "EA doesn't currently handle definitions of fields in unsafe classes. We will modify EA to allow importing the definitions of fields that are specified as unsafe, or in an unsafe class."